# Is it possible to get the id of an element without using the 'this' keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pick an element id without using the `this` keyword, I have set one parameter in function. The parameter has a message.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(msg){
alert(msg)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="me" onblur="check('this is test')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider passing _two_ parameters.

Comment: Short answer is of course it is possible.  You could `getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id` in your example but I'm guessing you need something more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

```
onblur="check(this, event)"

function check(elem, e){
   alert(e.target.id)
}
```

You can use the pass in the event object and access the `target` property.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/949Un/)**

But it is a good practice to avoid *inline event registration* and using javascript to attach events instead..

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="me" />
<input type="text" id="again" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
       inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', check); 
}

function check(e){
   alert(e.target.id)
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/949Un/1/)**

Comment: e (or event) doesn't just magically appear, did you test that?

Comment: What do you mean ? event will be in the scope of the handler.. So it is available along with `this`

Comment: @dandavis e (or event) does 'magically' appear when an event is used... hence the onblur.

Comment: @david - there was no onblur back then. now it seems a bit complicated and brittle, but it probably works on the simple demo.

Comment: Event event has the `event object`  associated with it.. It was already existing for the other events as well

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="me" onblur="check('this is test', this.id)" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="me" onblur="check('this is test', arguments[0].target.id )" />
```

Comment: can you explain 'arguments.callee'